# Java errors on MacOS 10.8.4 using MatLab2013a

Tags: java, macos, matlab, matlab-compiler

I am experiencing numerous problems with java in MatLab 2013a, for example while using pmode, matlabpool, creating stand alone applications etc.

Sometimes there is a work-around but this is not always the case.

Does anybody has a solution for this problem. Is there a patch or a downgraded java version that works for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that this is a different Java disaster from the one @JamesGrammatikos pointed out. I had to figure it out myself on R2012b. See [this bug report](http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/919688) at the MathWorks. To apply the workaround, read everything and follow the directions carefully as they didn't exactly try hard to make the patch into any sort of installer. Once, applied, everything works again, but looking at the patch code, there's still room for other stuff to break.

Answer (score 0):

A Java update last month ago pretty much destroyed most Java based programs on Macs (including Matlab for me). The update at this link fixed it for me.

http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572 (OS X 10.7, 10.8+)

Comment: Unfortunately, this version also don't fixed the issues I had with using the compiler:
    Depfun error: 'Java exception occurred:
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:286)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:321)'